# What would the correct regex be for this replacement?

Tags: regex

This is half a question and half a fun quiz, because the regex will be **ridiculously complicated** and hard to create.

If I was to do it myself (*because I actually need to use it*), I would write a file parser rather than a regex, although I know it's possible to use regex in this case, and I thought there was perhaps some StackOverflow coders who liked challenge.

As a "reward", I'll leave the question open for 7 days, at which point a **bounty of 150 reputation** will be attributed to the person with the correct answer. I'm aware that the answerer might probably have >3K of reputation, but rep is rep nonetheless, I presume. :)

The regex will have to turn:

```
[DllImport(EngineDll)]
public static extern int Graphics(int width, int height, int depth = default(int), int hertz = 60, int flags = (int)(GraphicsBufferType.Back | GraphicsBufferType.Depth));
```

Into:

```
public static int Graphics(int width, int height, int depth = default(int), int hertz = 60, int flags = (int)(GraphicsBufferType.Back | GraphicsBufferType.Depth))
{
    if (Engine.ThreadSafe)
    {
        lock (typeof(Dll))
        {
            return Dll.Graphics(width, height, depth, hertz, flags);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Dll.Graphics(width, height, depth, hertz, flags);
    }
}
```

Since **multiline is not needed at all**, you can have it all in 1 line if you find it easier to parse:

```
public static int Graphics(int width, int height, int depth = default(int), int hertz = 60, int flags = (int)(GraphicsBufferType.Back | GraphicsBufferType.Depth)) { if (Engine.ThreadSafe) { lock (typeof(Dll)) { return Dll.Graphics(width, height, depth, hertz, flags); } } else { return Dll.Graphics(width, height, depth, hertz, flags); } }
```

Now if it wasn't obvious enough, what is variable is the return type, the method name, the parameter types, the parameter names, whether the parameters have default values and in that case, the default values. The function may be a void, in which case there should be no return statement.

**On request**: Second input-output:

```
[DllImport(EngineDll)]
public static extern void EndRender();
```

Output:

```
public static void EndRender()
{
    if (Engine.ThreadSafe)
    {
        lock (typeof(Dll))
        {
            Dll.EndRender();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Dll.EndRender();
    }
}
```

Again, 1-liners accepted.

Good luck! :)

*Note to all who might say I'm just lazy: Change question.*

Comment: I added the `fun` and `code-bowling` tags, since as you said it's a challenge and not really the right tool for the job.  But it looks interesting none the less...  Oh, and for clarity, what do you want to replace?  What are the rules for the transformation?  Are you just expecting parameter names added to the return calls?

Comment: @ircmaxell: I don't understand your question, sorry. Care to elaborate?

Comment: So the basics you want are the class name moved from source to destination, the input parameter list moved, and the parameter names appended to the two returns...  correct?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible for an unknown number of arguments.  I'd gladly eat my words here, but just my $0.02 (I can't see any direct replace that will do what I think you want me to do with no outside logic)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Correct. Unless the method is void, in which case you would not have a return statement, just the call. I don't know either if you can have an unknown amount of parameters.

Comment: I removed the `code-bowling` tag, since the goal is not to write a bastardized regex. The cleanest and shortest one isn't bad at all, rather wanted.

Comment: True, but it's also about writing something that's not best-practice (As you said before, writing a parser is the best method).  That's why I had added it...

Comment: I don't think you can get it done with a single replace. Repeating parameters are problematic unless you have a limit on the their number, and so is the optional `return`. It is possible, and not too complex, to *parse* that line, and build the string at the next step (or replace and use a callback, which is cheating). Now, how far should we take that? default values can be strings, which might contain anything. There could be comments anywhere. Attributes. Generics (of the function or the arguments' types).  Whole world of ugly.

Comment: The void/return problem is an easy fix, AFAIK. Moreover, default values are never strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quite do this with true regular expressions, because you need to be able to handle balanced parentheses in the default values. That said, there are regex dialects with extensions that allow you to handle this sort of thing, so let's get the ball rolling:

```
s/[DllImport(EngineDll)]\npublic\ static\ extern\ #boilerplate
  (?<method> #capturing group for the method signature
  (?<return>\w+)\ #Method return type
  (?<name>\w+)\( #Method name
  (?<parameter>\w+\ #parameter type
   (?<parname>\w+)\ #parameter name
   (=\ (?&DEFAULTVALUEREGEX))? #optional default value
   (?{$params = $+{parname}}) #Ok, so this isn't even pretending to be a regex 
                              # anymore. If anyone has any better ideas...
  )(?:,\ #parameter seperator
   \w+\ (?<par>\w+)\ (=\ (?&DEFAULTVALUEREGEX))?
   (?{ $params .= ", " . $+{par}}))* # more parameters
   \)); # boilerplate
  /
  public static $+{method} { if (Engine.ThreadSafe) { lock (typeof(Dll)) { return Dll.$+{name}($params); } } else { return Dll.$+{name}($params); }}
  /x
```

I haven't included the definition of the DEFAULTVALUEREGEX because that basically requires you to parse anything that's a valid C# expression, which would be large enough to obscure the rest of the logic. Also it uses the `(?{code})` construct, making it exceptionally dubious whether this even counts as a sort-of regular expression. Also I haven't tested it at all because I'm lazy like that, and it's really brittle (it'll break on a bunch of stuff that's still valid C#).

If anyone has any improvements, feel free to edit them in - that's why it's CWiki in the first place.

Comment: Without the nested parenthesis, do you think you'd have more of a chance? In the worst cast, the "default(...)" parameter isn't so frequent, I could add it in manually later on.

Comment: The nested parentheses are actually the easy part once you've committed to using "regex+" - the variable number of parameters combined with the fact that you need to transform them that's the big issue. Though seeing as there's a maximum of 536870911 parameters, it's theoretically *possible* to do just with regex...

Comment: @536870911: No. I want the regex to take less than a GiB. Condition just for you.

Answer (score 0):

So, what's wrong with this?

```
s/.*/public static int Graphics(int width, int height, int depth = default(int), int hertz = 60, int flags = (int)(GraphicsBufferType.Back | GraphicsBufferType.Depth)) { if (Engine.ThreadSafe) { lock (typeof(Dll)) { return Dll.Graphics(width, height, depth, hertz, flags); } } else { return Dll.Graphics(width, height, depth, hertz, flags); } }/;
```

Since it (probably) wasn't what you had in mind, there has to be another transformation that the same regex also has to do - otherwise what I provided is quite adequate for the job.

Comment: @Lazlo: if you only have to match one string and generate one other string, a regex of the form I showed meets the requirement; the input is the line you gave, the output is the line you requested - job complete.  Therefore, to be interesting, there must be at least two different input lines, with two different outputs.  But you've not given us the second case to work with - so there is no general way to answer your question.

Comment: *Sigh*, alright. Programmers sometimes... EDIT: The code isn't even right. You should at least input my base code, as you're doing a replacement.

Comment: @Lazlo: who else did you expect to find reading StackOverflow?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: To be honest, I actually enjoyed the comment, made me feel all fuzzy inside that someone else picked on the fact that I had only 1 in-out, while I hesitated to post it as is. I love S/O and programmers. :)

Comment: @Lazlo: The '.*' matches your base case...the output matches your requirements.  Agile programming - YAGNI!  You said that multilines were not required, so the input is all one line, for all it looks like it might be two in the question.  You didn't say anything about what has to be left untouched.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Multilines was not required for output.